# Array copying works in eclipse but no longer works in replit

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, replit

Okay so I am going to keep this short and sweet. I'm writing this code in a group project but I did my rough work in eclipse, after pasting it into replit Arrays.copyOf gets highlighted and I don't know why.

```
class Arrays 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)  
      {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] marks = new int[0];
        int mark;
        for(int i = -1; i < marks.length;)
        {
          System.out.println("Please enter a mark (Enter -1 to end): ");
          mark = sc.nextInt();
          if(mark == -1)
          {
            i = i + 2;
          }
          else if(mark < -1 || mark > 10)
          {
              System.out.println("Sorry, the mark must be between 0 and 10.");
          }
          else
          {
            i++;
            marks = Arrays.copyOf(marks, marks.length + 1);
            marks[i] = mark;
          }
        }
        for(int j : marks)
              System.out.println(j);
      }
}
```

Comment: May be because of your class name is also `Arrays` ? have you defined any package here?

Comment: hmm it's possible, I imported java.util.*; which worked in eclipse

Comment: What happens if you change the (your) class name of Arrays to something else? Is the problem still there?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `java.util` before `marks = Arrays.copyOf(marks, marks.length + 1);` like

```
marks = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(marks, marks.length + 1);
```

and of course, do the same for Scanner too, like

```
java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```